# Getting services to communicate with each other using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port

I am trying to get an api gateway to be able to successfully redirect requests to the correct spring boot microservice based on the URL. The following `application.yml` configuration worked for when I was running the project locally, but it seems that the api gateway is unable to find these services when I have them running via `docker-compose up`:

```
server:
  port:8080
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: user_service
          uri: 'http://localhost:8001'
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/users/**
        - id: user_service
          uri: 'http://localhost:8001'
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/business/**
        - id: book_service
          uri: 'http://localhost:8000'
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/books/**
        - id: payment_service
          uri: 'http://localhost:8002'
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/payment/**
```

The error I get when I do a postman test to, for example: `localhost:8080/api/books` is a

```
finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8000
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  api-gateway:
    image: perrywinkle/api-gateway:latest
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    build:
      context: BackEnd/bk_api_gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  bookeroo-frontend:
    image: perrywinkle/bookeroo-frontend:latest
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    build:
      context: FrontEnd/myfirstapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
    command: npm start
  
  books-ms:
    image: perrywinkle/books-ms:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    build:
      context: BackEnd/bookmicroservices
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /data/bookeroo-db

  login-ms:
    image: perrywinkle/login-ms:latest
    ports:
      - '8001:8001'
    build:
      context: BackEnd/loginmicroservices
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /data/bookeroo-db

  payment-ms:
    image: perrywinkle/payment-ms:latest
    ports:
      - '8002:8002'
    build:
      context: BackEnd/paymentmicroservices
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /data/bookeroo-db
```

I should also mention that my frontend node app also suffers from this issue (where it is unable to access the microservices via the gateway hosted on 8080).

Does `localhost` not play well with docker-compose? I've tried the solutions for the various related threads here on stack overflow (such as statically changing the urls to 0.0.0.0, etc.) and none of them have worked for me so far. Any input would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
After changing the `application.yml` to this, the responses are now getting through to the services:

```
server:
  port:8080
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: user_service
          uri: 'login-ms:8001'
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/users/**
        - id: user_service
          uri: 'login-ms:8001'
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/business/**
        - id: book_service
          uri: 'books-ms:8000'
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/books/**
        - id: payment_service
          uri: 'payment-ms:8002'
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/payment/**
```

However, postman testing to `localhost:8080/api/books` returns a completely error free 200 OK Response which is empty. I've tried to look at the services to see if any errors could have been "swallowed" but this does not seem to be the case. Inspecting the `books-ms` logs reveals that it has indeed received the request but seems to not be returning anything:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        book0_.book_id as book_id1_0_,
        book0_.book_author as book_aut2_0_,
        book0_.book_category as book_cat3_0_,
        book0_.book_image_url as book_ima4_0_,
        book0_.book_isbn as book_isb5_0_,
        book0_.book_price as book_pri6_0_,
        book0_.book_published_date as book_pub7_0_,
        book0_.book_summary as book_sum8_0_,
        book0_.book_title as book_tit9_0_,
        book0_.price_currency as price_c10_0_ 
    from
        books book0
```

Answer (score 1):

In a docker-compose network created with all the services in the compose file you can access other services using the service names (i.e. to connect to `payment-ms` connect to `payment-ms:8002`)

unless you want to access those services from outside the machine you don't need to expose the ports (meaning no need for the `ports` section in the compose file) cause they are all available to to each other in their inner docker network.

If you want to use the localhost type of configuration you can use this DNS name `host.docker.internal` though its the less preferable option (security wise)

Here's the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) take on that

Comment: Hi, the request is now getting through to the services. However, the microservices themselves do not seem to be returning its responses to the correct place because all I get is a status 200 OK. My application.yml is the only thing I changed as of now (just swapped out the localhost for the service names). Any recommendations for this?

Comment: what do you mean by the "correct place", are the responses just empty? if so try sending the same requests from outside and see what you get, and if possible add the output, errors, logs to the question as a new *UPDATE* section

Comment: yep, the responses, when sent to localhost:8080 return as 200 OK response requests (like the should) but there is no content. Worth noting that when I do the same request but directly to the where the services are hosted (e.g. localhost:8000/api/books) it returns the correct response. I've also added an update section with the new info. thanks for your help so far.

Comment: might be just a typo but in the first mention you've written `localhost:8080` and in the second `localhost:8000/api/books` these are two different ports, was this mistake only in the comment or also IRL? how are you confirming no data is being received? did you check the result in dev tools (if frontend application) or some debugger?

Comment: Nope that isn't a typo. It's because the point of my api gateway is to route requests on port 8080 to the correct microservice (on port 8000 in this case) based on the url given. The `application.yml ` supplied indicates this. 
I'm also checking this via simple postman testing as mentioned in the post.

Comment: are those applications working locally with the same setup?